# Sort a PagedList

Tags: android, sorting, pagedlist

I have implemented a PagedList in Kotlin for Android. When I scroll the list, it loads new pages just as it is supposed to do. Now I want to sort the items in the resultant full list.

In my DataSource, I tried

callback.onResult(schoolResponse.results.sortedBy { schoolField -> schoolField.school.name }, nextKey)

Of course, this sorts the items on each loaded page, instead of sorting the entire list.

So if there are five items per page, I would get:
A
D
G
H
M
B
C
P
R
T

instead of:
A
B
C
D
G
H
M
P
R
T

Anybody know how to sort a paged list?

Comment: If the data isn't sortable at its source (e.g., `ORDER BY` on a Room query), I think that you are out of luck. After all, the only way to sort the complete data set is to *have* the complete data set, and the Paging component is designed to *not have* the complete data set at any point in time. So, if `schoolResponse.results` is just a single page's worth of results, that's not going to work. If `schoolResponse` is the result of a Web service call, you need to tell the Web service to sort things the way that you want.

Comment: I was wondering whether I should load the data set into a Room database and then have my DataSource come from Room queries using "ORDER BY". The data set is rather large, so i have resisted that approach because of the initial time to the load the data set. But, as I believe you suggest, I can either have the large initial load time and have sorted output or dispense with Room and the large initial load time and be satisfied with an unsorted output. Thanks.